# Prevent copy-pasted base64 encoded images in WordPress post editor

Tags: wordpress, base64

When editing a post in the WordPress post editor, it's possible to directly copy-paste in an image.

The problem is, this stores image data in the database, increasing the database size and causing potential performance issues. (Consider that WordPress stores post revisions for every draft.)

Is it possible to disable this in order to prevent this from happening?

Answer (score 0):

I'm using [this plugin](http://wordpress.org/plugins/tinymce-remove-base-64-image/) to prevent copy-pasted base64 images. It doesn't completely disable it (it will check the editor 1,5 seconds and remove base64 images), but it seems like a decent workaround.